# Resetting Menu / Desktop

Tags: release-loki

I installed Loki over an older installation (prior version of Elementary) where I only saved my home partition (everything else was wiped clean).  What is the best way to reset the desktop so it is back to the default?  I tried copying in the files from /etc/skel, but that didn't seem to work (menu sort of appeared but standard apps in the launch bar did not).

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to reset only desktop settings or all programs settings?(including desktop)

If you want to reset all settings run this command and reboot:

```
sudo rm -rf .*
```

**Be sure to run this in your home directory**

If you want to reset only desktop you should delete only some of this files, but i do not know which, you should wait a reply from a developer.